# Обновление textarea ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, textarea

Весь текст из `textarea` сохраняется в файл. Как сделать обновление самой формы `textarea`, чтобы другой человек находящийся на этой ссылке мог видеть, как обновляется файл не нажимая кнопки *F5*?

```js
$(function() {
    var $textarea = $(".content");
    var content = $textarea.val();

    $textarea.tabby();

    $(".print").text(content);

    $textarea.focus();

    setInterval(function() {
        if (content !== $textarea.val()) {
            content = $textarea.val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "&t=" + encodeURIComponent(content)
            });
            $(".print").text(content);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<?php $path = $FOLDER."/".$name; ?>
<body>
<textarea name="contents" id="contents" class="content" spellcheck="true">
    <?php
    if (file_exists($path))
    {
        print htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($path));
    }
    ?>
</textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: как вариант, можно периодически (скажем, раз в секунду) опрашивать сервер на предмет обновлений содержимого файла через XHR. Если появился новый контент - отдавать его как JSON в обработчик XHR.

Comment: Я в этом не разбираюсь вообще, но заставить работать надо :D

Comment: А, это тогда к фрилансерам.

Comment: вот почитайте: [Comet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 1):

```
(function textServerForNewContent() {
    $.getJSON('/text.php', function(response) {
        if (response.newContent) {
            $(".print").text(content);
        }
        setTimeout(textServerForNewContent, 1000);
    });
}());
```

Решение может и не идеально но имеет право на жизнь.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо смотреть в сторону WebSocket. погуглите, по этому поводу много информации и разных решений.